# use private variable in inhertence

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Member {

private String name;
private String address;



public Member(String name,String address)
{

    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;


}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address)
{
     this.address = address;
}

public String toString()
{
return name +","+ " " + address; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Member m1=new Member("ravi","h-no :912");

    System.out.println(m1.toString());
}

}
```

i am trying to extend Member class.i should use only private variables.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Undergraduate extends Member {
private int numCourses;
private ArrayList<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();


public Undergraduate(String name, String address) {
    super(name,address);

}
public void addCourseGrade(String course,int grade)
{
    courses.add(course);
    //String grade1=String.valueOf(grade);
    grades.add(grade);
}
public double getAverageGrade() {
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i < grades.size() ; i++)
          sum = sum + grades.get(i);

                 //calculate average value
     double average=0;
     average=  sum / grades.size();

  return average;
}

public String toString()
{
return name +address;// i want to return undergraduate name and address here
}

public static void main(String args[])
{   
    Undergraduate undg = new Undergraduate("kimi", "hno 123");
    undg.addCourseGrade("CS500", 2);
    undg.addCourseGrade("CS560", 1);
    System.out.println(undg.toString());
    System.out.println(undg.getAverageGrade());
}
}
```

i am inheriting Member class and Undergraduate class
i want to return undergraduate name and address in toString() is it possible if i use private variables.

expected ouput:

```
kim hno 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, **you can't access `name` and `address` because they are `private` variables**, rather you can use the `getter` methods which are `public`, so you can access them in any class (i.e., not only subclass) as shown below in your `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
   return getAddress() + getName();
}
```

---

One more point to note is that because, `Undergraduate` IS-A `Member` (inheritance), you are able to call `getAddress()` and `getName()` without creating an object for `Member` class i.e., in non-subclasses (no inheritance), you need an object for the `Member` class to invoke the `public` (instance) methods.